# Write SQL query without knowing LHS and RHS in where clause

Tags: sql, dynamic, where-clause

I have a list of filters: [state,city,university].

Here are several of the filters:

```
'state' = "Tamil Nadu" / "Karnataka" / "Maharashtra" / "all"
```

Filter

```
'city' = "Chennai" / "Kanyakumari" / "Madhurai" / "Bangalore" / "Mysore" / "Dharwad" / "Mumbai" / "Pune" / "all"
```

Filter

```
" college" = any college in city / "all"
```

If the value of these individual elements is "all" then I don't have to include them in where clause. That means those elements for which the value is not "all", have to be included in where clause.

Like:

```
(If the filter "college" is "all")
Select college_name, branches from Colleges where state = state and city = city.

(If city and college is "all")
Select college_name, branches from Colleges where state= state.

(If all the filters have "all")
Select college_name, branches from Colleges.
```

How this can be done? Kindly help me.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres sql

Answer (score 0):

you can skip the parameters by checking them in where clause:

```
Select college_name, branches 
from Colleges 
where (state = 'all' or "state" = @state)
  and (city = 'all' or "city" = @city)
```